# How to convert array to object in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics

I am trying to typed the below utility function which takes in an array and return an object as below

```js
const convertListToMap = (list, key, secondKey) => {
  const map = {};
  
  for (const ele of list) {
    map[ele[key]] = ele[secondKey]
  }
  
  return map;
}


console.log(convertListToMap([{name: 'isaac', age: 17}, {name: 'john', age: 20}], 'name', 'age'));

console.log(convertListToMap([{race: 'chinese', language: 'mandarin'}, {race: 'malay', language: 'melayu'}], 'race', 'language'));
```

As you can tell `key` and `secondKey` is sort of dynamic, depending on the parameter `list`, so I guess `generics` is the way to go. Below is my attempt

```js
const convertListToMap = <
  T extends object,
  U extends keyof T,
  V extends keyof T
>(
  list: T[],
  key: U,
  secondKey: V
) => {
  const map = {} as Record<U, V>;
  for (const ele of list) {
    map[ele[key]] = ele[secondKey];
  }
  return map;
};
```

However, the above giving me error `Type 'T[U]' cannot be used to index type 'Record<U, V>'`, wondering which part I've done wrong?

**UPDATES**

My latest attempt is to update the signature of `map` as below

```js
  const map = {} as Record<T[U], T[V]>;
  for (const ele of list) {
    map[ele[key]] = ele[secondKey];
  }
  return map;
```

With this latest attempt, value assignment to `map` variable is fine, but I'm getting error at Record declaration line with below error

> Type 'T[U]' does not satisfy the constraint 'string | number | symbol'.
> Type 'T[keyof T]' is not assignable to type 'string | number | symbol'.
> Type 'T[string] | T[number] | T[symbol]' is not assignable to type 'string | number | symbol'.
> Type 'T[string]' is not assignable to type 'string | number | symbol'.
> Type 'T[string]' is not assignable to type 'symbol'.
> Type 'T[keyof T]' is not assignable to type 'symbol'.
> Type 'T[U]' is not assignable to type 'symbol'.
> Type 'T[keyof T]' is not assignable to type 'symbol'.
> Type 'T[string] | T[number] | T[symbol]' is not assignable to type 'symbol'.
> Type 'T[string]' is not assignable to type 'symbol'.ts(2344)

Comment: Ignore me (deleted the comment). I think the main problem is that your `map` is not type `Record<U, V>` since you're putting in the values from `T`, not the keys

Comment: @Phil: Good point, I even tried `const map = {} as Record<T[U], T[V]>;` but it doesn't work either haha

Comment: @Phil: I've finally found a solution, maybe can take a look if you're interested :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with the last attempt was that `Record` seemed to expect only `string | number | symbol`, and since TypeScript unsure what `T[U]` gonna be, hence it threw the error. I found that we can tell TS a little bit more about `T` as below

```js
const convertListToMap = <
  T extends { [key: string|number]: string | number },
  U extends keyof T,
  V extends keyof T
>(
  list: T[],
  key: U,
  secondKey: V
) => {
  const map = {} as Record<T[U], T[V]>;
  for (const ele of list) {
    map[ele[key]] = ele[secondKey];
  }
  return map;
};
```

From the above, we are telling typescript that `T` is gonna be an object with `key` of `string`, and the value is gonna be of type `string | number`, with that, TypeScript is happy with the definition `Record<T[U], T[V]>`

This solution works great and TS can infer correctly

```js
const personObj = convertListToMap([{name: 'isaac', age: 17}, {name: 'john', age: 20}], 'name', 'age')
// const personObj: Record<string, number>

const languageObj = convertListToMap([{race: 'chinese', language: 'mandarin'}, {race: 'malay', language: 'melayu'}], 'race', 'language')
// const languageObj: Record<string,string>
```